# Como exponer en C# la referencia a la Base de Datos para que sea accesible desde todos los formularios

Tags: c#

Entiendo que puede resultar un poco estúpida la pregunta pero llevo largo rato tratando de encontrar un ejemplo o la forma de colocar lo que se ve en el código de la captura que está funcionado correctamente en el Load del form pero quiero usar el objeto database desde todos los formularios de la applicacion y no estoy seguro que tipo de modulo o clase crear para esto.
Desde ya muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Este error me da al intentar colocar en una clase]

Comment: Y poner todo eso en una clase (estatica o no) que pueda ser vista por todos los formularios no funciono por algo en particular?

Comment: Eso intento pero obtengo un error y no logro resolver . Alli pego la otra captura para que veas

Comment: El codigo y los errores deber ir como texto, no como imagenes. Las imagenes son utiles solo si son absolutamente necesarias...

Comment: si lo se! a eso pero no podri mostrar el error en la 2da imagen, Gracias por tu apreciacion

Comment: yo veo que esta todo en rojo, pero no se cual es el error.. no sabe que es Enviroment? faltara un using? para que poner el set ahi?

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Todos comenzamos una vez no ?

Comment: Resolviste tu problema? Podrias usar una clase que tenga tus metodos CRUD con una conexion usando el patron Singleton, entonces no te hace falta tenerla en todos los formularios, solo llamadas al metodo necesario y seria mas facil de mantener tu codigo.

Comment: gBianchi no quiso ofenderte, pero tiene razon que no se ve que error te da lo que esta marcado en rojo. Deberias mostrar el listado de errores para saber que esta pasando.